# Label Images with overlapping objects for Instance Segmentation with Tensorflow Object Detection Api

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, object-detection-api

I used TensorFlow for object detection and now I wanted to try the instance segmentation with an Mask RCNN Model from tensorflow model zoo https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

I prepared the input data: original images, xml file with bounding boxes, png files as mask and created the TfRecords. It's working quite fine but the predictions are not very accurate. The mask contains a lot of the background.

I think this is because objects are overlapping each other in the images.

Is there a way to mask/label the training dataset so that each instance has a different color? 
(I'm not talking about the inference but about the training itself)

Like in the picture. Of course the white bounding boxes are not in my mask image. I added them to show that some instances are in the bounding box of another instance.

[image]

I would really appreciate some hints.

Comment: once you have the bounding boxes, if you can go box by box and get the corresponding binary mask (which can be extended to a binary mask of the whole image), and then use a mask rcnn like architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried a few things and came to the conclusion that I need more images to train my model. I have a lot of images with overlapping instance and not many where the instances are clearly seperated. 
I was hoping that there is a better way to tell the model which pixel belongs to which instance.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the DeepLab you will be able to do the segmentation with this tool - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab

Comment: A sample code for OP's specific problem could really help.

Comment: I already tried DeepLab and it's working fine for a simple segmentation without object detection. I found out that you can use the object_detection_api from tensorflow for an instance segmentation.

Comment: Segmentation can be done in many ways, including TF object detection api, facebook's detectron, and others.  Just wondering why is it marked -1 for the comment, when you get instance segmentation with deeplab  also ?

Comment: @Suman As I mentioned above, I already tried DeepLab and it's working fine for semantic segmentation but not for instance segmentation. At least I couldn't find a way how to use it for instance segmentation.If you have a link of an example or paper, I would really appreciate it if you could share it.